# Java ImageIO resource path

Tags: java, jar, ide

I have a Java program that runs fine in Eclipse - when I export an executable jar file it gives me an exception.

I know it is because I am giving it the wrong path but I do not know how to fix. I tried using `getClass().getResourceaAsStream()` (or sth. like that) but that did not work as well.

The code I am using at the moment is the following:

line 31:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/src/res/loading.png"));
```

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: have you tried using absolute path?

Comment: @dranrebdino absolute path works fine but I need the jar file to run on different computers - when I open the jar with e.g.  WinRar it contains the folder /res/ and the images...

Comment: Try just loading `loading.png` instead of `/src/res/loading.png`

Comment: @GROX13 does not work as well for me - same exception

Comment: getClass().getResource("/res/loading.png"), this returns a URL to the resource, but you should be able to use getResourceAsStream as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer using this gives me java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! Code: `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Tray.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/loading.png"));`

Comment: Have tried getClass() instead of Tray.class?

Comment: Eclipse wont allow me using this telling me: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object`

Comment: @piguy Create an instance A class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138003/discussion-between-piguy-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I created a simple project, made a directory called `res` and threw some images into it

[image: Project Structure]

Before anyone points out that this not Eclipse, it shouldn't matter, we've already established that the Jar file contains the `res` directory and images, it's about replicating the structure

I then wrote a really simple example...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        System.out.println(Test.class.getResource("/res/0.jpg"));
        System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/res/0.jpg"));
    }

}
```

which outputs...

```
file:/.../Test/build/classes/res/0.jpg
file:/.../Test/build/classes/res/0.jpg
```

No, before any points out the IDE's environment is different from the command lines, I also ran it from the command line...

```
java -jar Test.jar 
jar:file:/.../Test/dist/Test.jar!/res/0.jpg
jar:file:/.../Test/dist/Test.jar!/res/0.jpg
```

Comment: Time for bed :)